# encode json array from latin1

Tags: php, arrays, json, latin1

So i am very new to php and having problem with my array.

"Basically I have an array with 5 fields. 
Now the data is partially in latin1-german. But this let's the php output "null". How do I decode the array, that makes the php return the right text?"

edit:
So I altered the code (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT made it return nothing).
But the problem still remains. The special characters like "ä" and "ü" still make it return ":null".

```
// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM silberhell_app") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    $product["kategorie"] = $row["kategorie"];
    $product["beschreibung"] = $row["beschreibung"];
$product["bild"] = $row["bild"];
    $product["preis"] = $row["preis"];

array_map($product, "utf8_encode"); // encode array values
$products[] = $product; // insert product into array
}
$data = array(
//'success'   => 1,
'products' => $products
);
}
echo json_encode($data); // make it slightly more readable
?>
```

Comment: `array_map(utf8_encode, %arr)`? illegal syntax - this is PHP, not perl

Comment: Eeeh is this a function body? Why do you have a return statement in the middle of everything?

Comment: Also there is an else statement, but i see no if?

Comment: Just a comment on the while loop.  Creating a new $product array that's identical to the $row array is not needed.  You can do the array_map on the $row array directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly cleaned up, should work now:

```
$products = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    [...]

    array_map("utf8_encode", $product); // encode array values
    $products[] = $product; // insert product into array
}

$data = array(
    'success'   => 1,
    'products' => $products
);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // make it slightly more readable
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sadly the .php file is not outputing anything at the moment, is there something I missed to delete? I have updated the code above. I am very sorry, but this is my first time using php.

Comment: I thought you had that encapsulated in a method or function, since you used a `return` statement in your code :]

I updated the answer and fixed the array_walk call

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far! It now returns the values, but the special characters still return ":null". I have updated to the code above to the current state. Also removed the "success" dependency.

Comment: You could try this: `$products[] = array_map(function ($string) { return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'Windows-1252', 'utf-8'); }, $product);`  


Also, you shouldn't really mysql_* functions, since they are [deprecated](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Comment: This pretty much works! Thanks a lot for all your help!